# User defined iterators and performance

Tags: c++, iterator, containers

```
#ifndef EXERCISE_H_
#define EXERCISE_H_

#include <iostream>

typedef unsigned short ushort;

template <typename type_t>
class list{
    type_t data;
    ushort size_;
public:
    list<type_t> * head, * tail, * next, * prev;
    list();
    virtual ~list();

    ushort &size();

    void setData(type_t);
    type_t getData();

    virtual void push_back(type_t) = 0;
    virtual type_t pop_front() = 0;

    virtual void push_front(type_t) = 0;
    virtual type_t pop_back() = 0;
    virtual type_t front() = 0;
    virtual type_t back() = 0;
    virtual void print() = 0;

};

// DEFAULT CTOR
template <typename type_t>
list<type_t>::list() : size_(0){ this->head = this->tail = this->next = this->prev = nullptr;}

// DTOR
template <typename type_t>
list<type_t>::~list() {}

template <typename type_t>
ushort & list<type_t>::size(){
    return size_;
}


template <typename type_t>
void list<type_t>::setData(type_t value){
    this->data = value;
}

template <typename type_t>
type_t list<type_t>::getData(){
    return this->data;
}

/*********************\
*   DEQUEUE CLASS
\*********************/

template <typename type_t>
class dequeue : public list<type_t> {
public:
    void push_back(type_t);
    type_t pop_front();

    void push_front(type_t);
    type_t pop_back();

    type_t front();
    type_t back();
    void print();
};

// PUSH_BACK func
template <typename type_t>
void dequeue<type_t>::push_back(type_t value){
    list<type_t> * item = new dequeue;
    if (!item) throw std::bad_alloc();

    item->setData(value);

    if (this->tail) {
        this->tail->next = item;
        item->prev = this->tail;
    }
    this->tail = item;
    ++this->size();
    if (!this->head) this->head = this->tail;
}

// POP_BACK func
template <typename type_t>
type_t dequeue<type_t>::pop_back(){
    if(!this->head) throw std::out_of_range("List is empty");

    list<type_t> * item;
    type_t value;

    if(this->tail && this->tail != this->head){
        item = this->tail;
        value = this->tail->getData();
        this->tail = this->tail->prev;
        this->tail->next = nullptr;

        delete item;
    }
    else{
        value = this->head->getData();
        delete this->head;
        this->head = this->tail = nullptr;
    }
    --this->size();
    return value;
}


template <typename type_t>
void dequeue<type_t>::push_front(type_t value){
    list<type_t> * item = new dequeue;
    if (!item) throw std::bad_alloc();

    item->setData(value);
    item->prev = nullptr;

    if(this->head){
        item->next = this->head;
        this->head->prev = item;
    }
    this->head = item;
    ++this->size();
    if(!this->tail) this->tail = this->head;
}

template <typename type_t>
type_t dequeue<type_t>::pop_front(){
    if(!this->head) throw std::out_of_range("Empty list");

    list<type_t> * item;
    type_t value;

    if(this->head && this->head != this->tail){
        value = this->head->getData();
        item = this->head;
        this->head = this->head->next;
        this->head->prev = nullptr;

        delete item;
    }
    else{
        value = this->tail->getData();
        delete this->tail;
        this->head = this->tail = nullptr;
    }

    --this->size();
    return value;
}

template <typename type_t>
type_t dequeue<type_t>::front(){
    return this->head->getData();
}

template <typename type_t>
type_t dequeue<type_t>::back(){
    return this->tail->getData();
}

template <typename type_t>
void dequeue<type_t>::print(){
    int count = this->size();
    for(int i=0; i < count; i++)
        std::cout << pop_front() << " ";
}


#endif /* EXERCISE_H_ */
```

I have created a double ended container. But I have doubts about its efficiency in terms of performance. So can you please criticize the code? What can be done extra? For instance to shorthen the code? And the second thing I want to use algorithms of STL. How can I create my own iterators?

Comment: You likely meant to post to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: ^--- Read their How to Ask first though.